# Three.JS - How to get access to "Circlegeometry" and see if its working?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've recently discovered THREE.js and i got everything to work. I've implemented it like this in my html.

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
```

My question is, how do i get access to the "extras"? I want to use CircleGeomtry. I've looked around at their documentation but I'm not sure how I implement it in my HTML.

This is what it says in their documentation

```
src/extras/geometries/CircleGeometry.js
```

Do I have to download it? Or can i link to it like I have above?

Comment: I don't think so, Circlegeometry might be a part of three.js only. Here this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410980/three-js-circle-remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the source code at the three.js url you posted for `CircleGeometry`, you will see that `CircleGeometry` is included in that file.

```
THREE.CircleGeometry = function ( radius, segments, thetaStart, thetaLength ) {
    THREE.Geometry.call( this );

    radius = radius || 50;

    thetaStart = thetaStart !== undefined ? thetaStart : 0;
    thetaLength = thetaLength !== undefined ? thetaLength : Math.PI * 2;
    segments = segments !== undefined ? Math.max( 3, segments ) : 8;

    // snipped...
}
```

So you don't need to include any extra scripts at all.  Just instantiate your circle.

```
var circleGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(10);
```

---

The "extras" in three.js are all included in the distributed library.  The source code for the library is split into many files to keep the codebase organized.  But don't confuse that with the built library script which has all those files combined into one to make it easy to include on a webpage.

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot! The documentation confused me so I thought I would have to include something else. Thanks!

Comment: @CheesePuffs Three.js lacks good documentation.  To use it well you better get used to inspecting the source.  Don't be afraid to see what arguments constructors expect, or what things are named by searching the source code for those terms.